# getting error while using alias in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to subtract two columns and fetch the result if the difference is greater then 100 in hive. I have written the following query:

```
select District.ID,Year,(volume_IN-volume_OUT) as d1 from petrol where d1>100;
```

but I am getting error.

The table column names are:
**District.ID, Distributer name, volume_IN ,volume_OUT, Year**

Please help me, Is there any error in the query. I am new to the hive.

Comment: `District.ID`  - that's a strange name for a column. Change it to something like `District_id`. Also `Distributer name` to `Distributer_name`

Answer (score 0):

One of the Limitations of hive is you cannot refer the alias you used in the same query
Try writing a subquery, may be something like below

```
select * from (select District_ID,year, (volume_IN-volume_OUT) as d1 from petrol) t1 where d1>100;
```